# Mapnik3 + python3 + Postgis

Tags: postgis, mapnik

I've installed mapnik3, python bindings, and postgis (and imported a pbf file into postgis), and can't seem to even make it generate a simple map as a png file.

Specifically - where can I find examples of a working style.xml file which will actually work with freshly imported OSM data. All tutorials that I can find are related to mapnik 2.x.

Comment: Please post your exact steps so far and where exactly it fails.

Comment: I tried generating a style file using http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik/ and using it when rendering a map (example render.py script in the openstreetmaps wiki), it spews out a RuntimeError: failed to initialize projection with: '&srs900913;' in Map of 'osm.xml'

Comment: Probably downgrading to 2.x is the best solution. I'm not sure if mapnik3 is actually used that much - most of the open source tooling use mapnik 2.x.